# UE4: output game frames to file

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

**This applies to Unreal Engine 4.9**

Each frame, I'd like to save it to file (overwriting the existing one).

For a simple D3D11 demo that I have made, I've been able to do this with:

```
void Engine::CaptureFrame(D3DX11_IMAGE_FILE_FORMAT format, const LPCTSTR fileName){

    backbuffer->GetResource(&resource);
    ID3D11Texture2D* texture;
    HRESULT hResult = resource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&texture));
    D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(deviceContext, texture, format, fileName);

    //Clean up
    texture->Release();
    resource->Release();
}
```

I have done this with OpenGL, too, using a library called "[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)".

I don't want to modify UE4 source and am looking for a way to "hook" into UE4 and "capture" the frame.

I've managed to do this with [Open Broadcasting Software](https://obsproject.com/), but I'd like to do this natively, within UE4, either via c++ or blueprints.

I am also aware that [I can do this from the editor](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/Screenshots/index.html), but that is not what I want to do. I want to do this at run-time, automatically.

How can I go about this? Is it even possible?

Comment: It should be pretty obvious from my question that I have Googled this. If you have found something more concrete that shows how to do this with code or blueprints, then please share it rather than posting sarcastic comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else who wants to do this, you have a couple of options.

**Option A**

If you don't care how many screenshot files are generated and don't care what they are called, then you can use a blueprint:

[image]

The images will be output to `\Unreal Projects\ProjectName\Saved\Screenshots\Windows` where `ProjectName` is the name of your project.

**Option B**

If you don't want multiple screenshot files and need control over where they go, then you can do this via code:

```
//Called every frame
void AMyDempActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    FString filename = "test.png";
    FScreenshotRequest::RequestScreenshot(filename, false, false);

}
```

Here is the documentation on [FScreenshotRequest](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/FScreenshotRequest/RequestScreenshot/index.html)