# Unreal Engine 4: save rendered frame to memory

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Previously, I was looking to output frames rendered by UE4 to file.

I managed to do this and the details can be found in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488681/ue4-output-game-frames-to-file)

The function to out put the frame to file is:

```
 FScreenshotRequest::RequestScreenshot(filename, false, false);
```

Now, instead of writing to file, I would like to write to memory. I don't want to write to file and then read into memory.

I have been digging through the source code and found where screenshots are being made, but am having some trouble.

`ViewportClient->ProcessScreenShots(this);` is being called on line `1012` of `UnrealClient.cpp`

Following that, I found that the screenshot is actually being generated here:

```
bScreenshotSuccessful = GetViewportScreenShot(InViewport, Bitmap);
```

So, after finding all the bits that I think I need, I tried to recreate it in a custom Actor:

```
    UGameViewportClient* gameViewport = GEngine->GameViewport;
    FViewport* InViewport = gameViewport->Viewport;
    TArray<FColor> Bitmap;

    bool bScreenshotSuccessful = GetViewportScreenShot(InViewport, Bitmap);
    if (bScreenshotSuccessful){
        FIntVector Size(InViewport->GetSizeXY().X, InViewport->GetSizeXY().Y, 0);
        TArray<uint8> CompressedBitmap;
        FString ScreenShotName = TEXT("out.png");
        FImageUtils::CompressImageArray(Size.X, Size.Y, Bitmap, CompressedBitmap);
        FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile(CompressedBitmap, *ScreenShotName);
    }
```

For some reason, `bool bScreenshotSuccessful = GetViewportScreenShot(InViewport, Bitmap);` throws an `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000020.` exception.

I think the error has something to do with this line:

```
Viewport->ReadPixels(Bitmap, FReadSurfaceDataFlags(), ViewRect)
```

I've treid 'googeling' for what an 'Access violation' is, and it seems it is something to do with a null pointer or something like that, but I am still not able to figure this out as I'm rather new to c++.

**Question**

How can I fix this so that `bScreenshotSuccessful` is true?

**NOTE**: I realise that `FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile(CompressedBitmap, *ScreenShotName);` attempts to save to file, despite me saying that is not what I want to do, so please ignore that as if I have the bitmap, I can compress and stream it.

Answer (score 2):

You have ViewRect just of three points instead of four and in wrong format. Try this snippet:

```
FIntRect Rect(0, 0, InViewport->GetSizeXY().X, InViewport->GetSizeXY().Y);
bScreenshotSuccessful = GetViewportScreenShot(InViewport, Bitmap, Rect);
```